# timeval to uint64_t network bits

Tags: c, timeval

I am looking to append timeval fields into my custom packet header. Facing issues with type conversion.

My custom fields in the header

```
struct pkthdr {
    uint64_t sec;
    uint64_t usec;
}
```

Linux timeval struct

```
struct timeval {
    long tv_sec;        /* seconds */
    long tv_usec;   /* and microseconds */
}
```

Initialization

```
struct pkthdr *hdr;
struct timeval *tm;
gettimeofday(&tm, 0);
hdr->sec = htonl(tm->tv_sec);
hdr->usec = htonl(tm->tv_usec);
```

Following lines cause segmentation error

```
hdr->sec = htonl(tm->tv_sec);
hdr->usec = htonl(tm->tv_usec);
```

Comment: Do you have a question as well?

Comment: Please be explicit with exactly what you are trying to do and how it is not working.  Adding code showing your attempt can give us a pretty good idea of what you are attempting to accomplish.

Comment: Have fixed my question. Please check now @chr

Answer (score 0):

You have created pointers to `struct timeval` and `struct pkthdr`, but you have not actually allocated any memory to point to, so you are invoking undefined behavior when you try to assign a value to `hdr->sec` and `hdr->usec`

You are also passing in the wrong type to `gettimeofday` as you are passing in a `struct timeval **` rather than a `struct timeval`.

Try, instead, creating the actual structs instead of pointers to them:

```
struct pkthdr hdr;
struct timeval tm;
gettimeofday(&tm, NULL);
hdr.sec = htonl(tm.tv_sec);
hdr.usec = htonl(tm.tv_usec);
```

Check to make sure the data in `hdr.sec` and `hdr.usec` are actually what you want, as that might not be correct.  I have some reservations about use of `htonl` since that deals with 32-bit data while your intended result is 64 bits.